# Constant messages on I/O error on same sectors

Tags: hard-drive, smart, badblocks

I have the following messages on console

[image]

They say:

```
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata1.00: error: { UNC }
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1476687273
usbhid 6-1.2.3:1.1: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
```

and so on.

The questions are:

1) What does this error mean? Does this just mean bad sector surface?

2) Can I fix bad surface? Drive is almost empty and I don't see any reason to throw it away.

3) Why the number of sector is often the same? (sometimes it occur some different sector numbers)

4) Why this error appears not always, but probably just when I am turning on my KVM switch? (it is seen by command line prompt scrolled not very far up)

5) How USB is related? Is it just interlieved unrelated message?

I have tried to run `fsck` by creating

```
touch /forcefsck
```

and also ran

```
smartctl -t long
```

with no apparent result. Also what means this:

```
$ sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.19.0-56-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%     23618         1476686720
# 2  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%     23618         1476686720
```

?

Also

```
$ sudo smartctl -i /dev/sda
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.19.0-56-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.11
Device Model:     ST31500341AS
Serial Number:    9VS12GGW
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 010dd79ef
Firmware Version: CC1H
User Capacity:    1,500,301,910,016 bytes [1.50 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Sat Mar 26 14:27:30 2016 MSK
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

**UPDATE**

```
$ sudo smartctl -A /dev/sda
[sudo] password for dims:
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.19.0-56-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   088   088   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       56870243
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   100   095   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       91
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   087   087   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       560
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   080   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       115544838
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   073   073   000    Old_age   Always       -       23658
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       86
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       1115
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       4295032845
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   066   066   000    Old_age   Always       -       34
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   054   051   045    Old_age   Always       -       46 (Min/Max 43/48)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   046   049   000    Old_age   Always       -       46 (0 22 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   026   021   000    Old_age   Always       -       56870243
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       90
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       90
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       21590800620263
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1672609860
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2887754751
```

Comment: Could you post the results of `sudo smartctl -A /dev/sda`?

Comment: Done, see my update please

Answer (score 1):

Your drive is failing, and this is likely irreparable.

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%     23618         1476686720
# 2  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%     23618         1476686720
```

This means that when you ran a self test with `smartctl -t long`, the result was a read failure about 10% of the way into the drive. It doesn't tell you the result as part of the `smartctl -t` command, because this would tie up your terminal for several hours - it should tell you how to access the results.

Continuing to use the drive may result in silent data corruption, or complete failure. I'd strongly suggest replacing it.

Comment: I don't believe surface problem is irreparable. Hard drive is made of rigid plates, covered with magnetic material. If some sector is damaged, it should be possible to mark it not to use. The question is how to do this. This was possible even in MS DOS, don't see any reason it is impossible in XXI century.

Comment: @Dims If one sector fails, it is highly likely that others will too - and you will soon run out of spare sectors. Also, you will have lost any data stored in that sector. The drive automatically re-allocates sectors; that is what the `Reallocated_Sector_Ct` SMART attribute refers to.

Comment: Okay, let's don't speak about what happen in future. Currently one sector is bad and I wish to mark it out of use. By some reason it doesn't happen automatically. How to force?

Comment: @Dims Writing to the sector should tell the drive that you don't care about the contents of that sector, so it can reallocate it without attempting recovery.

Comment: Are there automatic utilities or something? It was Norton Disk Doctor at DOS times for example which drew nice screen with bad blocks marked with red `B`s.